# How do I add a button to my code that changes something on a timed basis?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a working traffic light in JavaScript that changes every time I press the button, how do I make it so if I press another button it will change color automatically on a timed basis?

My current code is the following:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
#black {
    background: black;
    padding: 20px;
    width: 150px;
    height: 450px;

}
#red {
    border-radius: 100px;
    background: red;
    width: 130px;
    height: 130px;
    position: relative;
    top: 10px;
    left: 10px;

}

#amber {
    border-radius: 100px;
    background: orange;
    width: 130px;
    height: 130px;
    position: relative;
    top: 20px;
    left: 10px;
}

#green {
    border-radius: 100px;
    background: green;
    width: 130px;
    height: 130px;
    position: relative;
    top: 30px;
    left: 10px;
}
    </style>
</head>
<body>

<script>
var seq = [["red","grey","grey"],["red","orange","grey"],["grey","grey","green"],["grey","orange","grey"]];
var y = 0;
function lights() {
    if (y < 4){
        var current = seq[y];
        var r = current[0];
        var a = current[1];
        var g = current[2];
        document.getElementById("red").style.background= r;
        document.getElementById("amber").style.background= a;
        document.getElementById("green").style.background = g;
        y++
    } else {
        y = 1
        document.getElementById("red").style.background= "red";
        document.getElementById("green").style.background= "grey";
        document.getElementById("amber").style.background = "grey";
    }
}
</script>
<div id="black">
<button onclick=lights()>Next cycle</button>
<div id="red"></div>
<div id="amber"></div>
<div id="green"></div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: please provide some code

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  You can take the [tour] first and learn [ask] a good question and create a [mcve].  That makes it easier for us to help you.

Comment: In order to get some helps, you need to give us your HTML, CSS and Javascript code related to this issue.

Comment: https://www.google.co.uk/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=javascript%20run%20function%20every%20n%20seconds

Answer (score 0):

If you want to schedule some code to run once after a certain amount of time has passed, use `setTimeout`.  For example if you have a function `doColorChange` that takes a `color` argument, then in your click handler you could say something like:

```
doColorChange('green'); // set the color now
setTimeout(function () {doColorChange('yellow');}, 2000);
setTimeout(function () {doColorChange('red');}, 4000);
```

Note that the functions you pass to `setTimeout` are not guaranteed to run after exactly the amount of time you specify.  They are queued up and become eligible to run after that amount of time.

If you want to have the same code run over and over again, you can use `setInterval` instead.  For example if you have a `toggleColor` function you could do

```
setInterval(toggleColor, 2000);
```

to call it (roughly) every 2 seconds.

Answer (score 0):

Hello please revised the following code, hope this works for you. It's not using any jQuery only raw JS and HTML.

**traffic-light.js**

```
// Initialize variables at runtime
var currentSignalState = null,
    previousSignalState = null,
    trafficLight,
    signalChangeLoop;

// Fire the constructor when DOM is available
window.onload = function () {
    trafficLight = document.getElementById("traffic-light");
    construct();
};

// Constructor function definition
function construct(){

    // Assign initial values for your signal states
    currentSignalState = "green";

    // Between Green and Red states is alwasy yellow so let's initialize it
    previousSignalState = "yellow";

    // When DOM is ready the paragraph can be found and we can then assign the initial value of the state
    trafficLight.innerHTML = currentSignalState;
}


// Manually change the traffic light's value
function changeTrafficSignal(){

    // Local variable representing the next state
    var newSignalState = "";

    // Between Green and Red is always Yellow
    if(currentSignalState == "green" || currentSignalState == "red"){

        newSignalState = "yellow";

    // If state is Yellow and is coming from a Red state
    } else if(currentSignalState == "yellow" && previousSignalState == "red" ){

        newSignalState = "green";

    // Will catch  state Yellow coming from Green
    } else{

        newSignalState = "red";

    }

    // Update our global values to be used on next iteration
    previousSignalState = currentSignalState;
    currentSignalState = newSignalState;

    trafficLight.innerHTML = newSignalState;
}

// Initiate an interval loop to change the traffic signal state
function startTrafficSignalAuto(){

    // *Suggested: alter to pass a parameter and make the interval value dynamic
    signalChangeLoop = setInterval(changeTrafficSignal, 2000);

}

// Stop the interval loop
function stopTrafficSignalAuto(){

    clearInterval(signalChangeLoop);

}
```

**index.html**

```
<!-- Loads the Javascript and fires the constructor -->
<script src="traffic-light.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<!-- Paragraph where the value of the current traffic light state is displayed-->
<p id="traffic-light"></p>

<!-- Will change the signal state based on current and previous signal states -->
<button onclick="changeTrafficSignal()">Manual Change</button>

<!-- Will initiate the interval to auto change || Sugested: supply a dynamic time by passing it as a parameter -->
<button onclick="startTrafficSignalAuto()">Automatic Start</button>

<!-- Will stop the interval loop -->
<button onclick="stopTrafficSignalAuto()">Automatic Stop</button>
```

Comment: Thank you for your help, if possible could you look at the code I posted above and try and implement the set interval function into it so it works properly.